# How does the JVM guarantee the visibility of member variable modifications in the referenced object when using synchronized?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to know how does the JVM guarantee the visibility of member variable modifications in the referenced object when using synchronized.

I know synchronized and volatile will provide visibility for variable modifications.

```java
class Test{
    public int a=0;

    public void modify(){
        a+=1;
    }
}


//Example:

// Thread A:
 volatile Test test=new Test();
 synchronized(locker){
   test.modify();
 }

// then thread B:
synchronized(locker){
   test.modify();
}

// Now, I think test.a==2 is true. Is it ok? How JVM implements it?
// I know the memory barrier, does it flush all cache to main storage?
```

Thread A call modify in a `sychronized` block first, and then pass the object to thread B (Write the reference to a `volatile` variable.).
Then thread B call modify again (in `synchronized`).

Is there any guarantee for a==2? And how is the JVM implemented?

Comment: Your example code doesn't match the scenario you describe, and it isn't complete,  Please update your Question so that we can be sure we understand what you are really asking.

Comment: @StephenC OK, I edit this code.

Comment: and yes, a will equal 2 after A and B have run. and you don't need volatile here.

Comment: That is still not a complete example.  Hint: If I can't copy it into files, compile it and run it, it is not complete.  In this case there are still important details missing.  (@NathanHughes is making some assumptions ....)

Comment: @Stephen C OK, I will edit it soon

Comment: That is what [mcve] means, better for everybody not to have to assume anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your (still incomplete!) example, if we can assume the following:

1. The code in thread A initializing `test` is guaranteed to run before thread B uses it.
2. The `locker` variable contains a reference to the same object for threads A & B.

then we can prove that `a == 2` will be true at the point you indicate.  If precondition 1 is not guaranteed, then thread B may get an NPE.  If precondition 2 is not guaranteed (i.e. threads A and B *may* synchronize on different objects) then there is not a proper happens-before relationship to ensure that thread B sees the result of thread A's actions on `a`.

(@NathanHughes commented that the `volatile` is unnecessary.  I wouldn't necessarily agree with that.  It depends on details of your example that you still haven't show us.)

---

> How JVM implements it?

The actual implementation is Java platform and (in theory) version specific.  The JVM spec Memory Model places constraints on how a program that obeys "the rules" will behave.  It is entirely implementation specific how that actually happens.

> I know the memory barrier, does it flush all cache to main storage?

That is implementation specific too.  There are different kinds of memory barrier that work in different ways.  The JIT compiler will emit native code that uses the *appropriate* instructions to meet the guarantees required by the JLS.  If there is a way to do this *without* doing a full cache flush then the implementation *may* do that.

(There is a JVM command line option to tell the JIT compiler to output the native code.  If you really want to know what is happening under the hood, that is a good place to start looking.)

But if you are trying to understand / analyze your application's thread-safety, you *should* be doing it in terms of the Java Memory Model.  Also, use higher level concurrency abstractions that allow you to avoid the lower level pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

Visibility between threads is enforced with [Memory Barriers/Fences](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/memory-barriersfences.html). In case of `synchronized` block JVM will insert a memory barrier after the execution of the block completes.

JVM implements memory barriers with CPU instruction e.g. a store barrier is done with `sfence` and load barrier is done with `lfence` instruction on x86. There is also `mfence` and possibly other instructions which can be specific to CPU architecture.